# Android onItemClick method not working for item of ids other than 0

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have a problem with onItemClick method in android.
I know other people have encountered such problems, found some references to their questions on SO, read about the answers provided and some other articles on the internet but it didn't help. Things seem a bit different in my case.

I have a listview of some objects for which I want to show details when they're clicked. But Awkwardly the listener is working fine for only the first object of the listview. The app keeps aborting when I click on other elements of the listview. I can't figure out what's going on.
As I was using the id to retrieve the object I tried changing the id by the position, which didn't work either.

Here is the code of the onCreate method in my activity (DrinkCategoryActivity)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);

        ArrayAdapter<Drink> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Drink.drinks
        );

        ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);
        listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listDrinks,
                                    View itemView, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) id);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
```

My DrinkActivity (the one that should show me the details of each Drink object when clicked in the listview) onCreate method code is shown below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        int drinkId = (int) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKID);
        Drink drinkItem = Drink.drinks[drinkId];

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drink_image);
        image.setImageResource(drinkItem.getImageResourceId());

        TextView drink_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drink_name);
        drink_name.setText(drinkItem.getName());

        TextView drink_description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drink_description);
        drink_description.setText(drinkItem.getDescription());

        TextView drink_price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.drink_price);
        String price = ""+drinkItem.getPrice();
        drink_price.setText(price);
    }
```

I don't know whether there is something wrong with the xml files so here they are :

activity_drink_category.xml goes below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.DrinkCategoryActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include
            layout="@layout/customer_screen_toolbar_layout"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/list_drinks"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And activity_drink.xml goes here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.DrinkActivity">
    <include
        layout="@layout/customer_screen_toolbar_layout"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drink_image"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drink_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drink_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/drink_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#EB8E13"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help will be valuable. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean aborting by "The app keeps aborting when I click on other elements of the listview"?

Comment: I mean the app stops abruptly with this message : App has stopped. Open app again

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass "**Position**" instead of "**id**" in Intent. As you describe above its works fine for the first position. Then you need to Use **position**

```
intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) position);


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);

        ArrayAdapter<Drink> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Drink.drinks
        );

        ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);
        listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listDrinks,
                                    View itemView, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @VishalSojitra for your prompt answer !

Comment: Tried with position as you said but the problem persists. The app stopped abruptly with the pop-up : App has stopped, Open app again